# How to filter date using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I'm creating one HTML report which has to show order details as per date selection. The order details stored in JSON file as given below :

```
[
  {
    "storeName": "ireland",
    "langCode": "en_IE",
    "testCaseName": "Guest User Checkout - Credit Card",
    "orderID": "4001820209",
    "date": "12-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
    "cartTotal": "19.98"
  },
  {
    "storeName": "denmark",
    "langCode": "en_DK",
    "testCaseName": "Guest User Checkout - Credit Card",
    "orderID": "6001825084",
    "date": "12-02-2019 15:37:35.140",
    "cartTotal": "338 DKK"
  },
  {
    "storeName": "united_kingdom",
    "langCode": "en_GB",
    "testCaseName": "Guest User Checkout - Credit Card",
    "orderID": "7002541022",
    "date": "13-02-2019 15:45:08.038",
    "cartTotal": "13.04"
  }
]
```

The HTML report would be look like this :

[image]

I want to take all order dates from this JSON file uniquely. Time needs to be removed and if same date already added into the HTML then skip it. Expected date order on HTML should be :

- 12-02-2019
- 13-02-2019
- 14-02-2019

If user clicks on that particular date then it should display all order placed on that date.

I have written below jQuery/javascript function to read the date and add into html but not sure how to make them unique.

This will call on page load

```
function myFunction() {
    createList();
    $.getJSON('order-detail.json', function (item) {
        item.forEach(function (data) {
                addItemsInList(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Create un-ordered list

```
function createList() {

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.setAttribute('id', 'order-dates');

    var div = document.getElementById('orderDateContainer');
    div.appendChild(ul);
}
```

Append dates in the list

```
function addItemsInList(data){

    var ul = document.getElementById('order-dates');
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('class', 'ord-date');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('class', 'record-viewer');
    a.setAttribute('href','#recordContent');
    a.innerHTML=data.date;
    a.setAttribute('onclick','tableCreater()');
    li.appendChild(a);
}
```

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by unique?

Comment: Date should be display like `12-02-2019` then `13-02-2019` and so on. Time should be removed

Comment: Ah.. I see the issue, you are assigning same id to each element, while id means unique. So assign id as "order-dates" + index and then use the same to add date to each element.

Comment: Let me know if that works

Comment: That id `order-dates` is for <ul> tag and its unique. My requirement pick the date from JSON file remove the time from it and add into `<ul>` tag if the same date is not already added

Comment: sorry, that I didn't see. Ignore.

Comment: send date as a parameter to a function which will sort and return JSON according to that param value.

Comment: adding a working snippet will help us to fix your problem more easily.

Comment: Check if this works @NarendraR : https://jsbin.com/yanenanofo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use [moment](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js/) js to parse dates so you can change date format and process things with `date object` and get a unique list by [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

*OR* you can just use substring to get your date by `dateTimeString.substr(0,10)`

```js
const datetime_dates = [
  "12-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
  "12-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
  "13-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
  "13-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
  "13-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
  "14-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
];

const get_unique_dates = (dates) => {
  const dates_only = dates.map(date => moment(date, "DD-MM-YYY HH:mm:ss.SSS").format("DD-MM-YYYY"));

  const unique_dates = [...new Set(dates_only)];
  return unique_dates;
}
console.log(get_unique_dates(datetime_dates));

// example with your data
const orders = [
  {
    "storeName": "ireland",
    "langCode": "en_IE",
    "testCaseName": "Guest User Checkout - Credit Card",
    "orderID": "4001820209",
    "date": "12-02-2019 15:37:30.201",
    "cartTotal": "19.98"
  },
  {
    "storeName": "denmark",
    "langCode": "en_DK",
    "testCaseName": "Guest User Checkout - Credit Card",
    "orderID": "6001825084",
    "date": "12-02-2019 15:37:35.140",
    "cartTotal": "338 DKK"
  },
  {
    "storeName": "united_kingdom",
    "langCode": "en_GB",
    "testCaseName": "Guest User Checkout - Credit Card",
    "orderID": "7002541022",
    "date": "13-02-2019 15:45:08.038",
    "cartTotal": "13.04"
  }
]

const order_dates = orders.map(order => order.date);
const unique_order_dates = get_unique_dates(order_dates);
console.log(unique_order_dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For filtering, you better do it in the backend for performance wise by requesting ajax every time user click to your `date link`

Comment: `TypeError: data.date.map is not a function` in my case even though i have added moment.min.js

Comment: add an example with your order data. Actually, you can also get date string by slicing your datetime string if you don't need to process with date object.

Comment: There is no need for a date library to do this, the dates will sort just fine as strings. Converting to Date then back to string just to trim the time is very inefficient compared to say `date.split(' ')[0]` or `date.substr(0,10)`.

Answer (score 1):

With only slight modifications to your existing functions, you could only loop over the unique dates and add them as before.

1. In `myFunction` we now reduce the data to only unique strings of dates, stripping away the time. Logic of the reducer is extracted to `collectIfUniqueDateFromOrder` function.

   ```
   function myFunction() {
     createList();

     $.getJSON('order-detail.json', function (data) {
       const uniqueDateStrings = data.reduce(collectIfUniqueDateFromOrder, []);

       uniqueDateStrings.forEach(addItemsInList);
     });
   }

   function collectIfUniqueDateFromOrder (uniqueDates, order) {
     var dateStringWithoutTime = order.date.split(" ")[0];

     if (!uniqueDates.includes(dateStringWithoutTime)) {
       uniqueDates.push(dateStringWithoutTime);
     }

     return uniqueDates;
   }
   ```
2. In `addItemsInList` we only handle date strings

   ```
   function addItemsInList(dateString) {
     var ul = document.getElementById('order-dates');
     var li = document.createElement('li');
     li.setAttribute('class', 'ord-date');
     ul.appendChild(li);
     var a = document.createElement('a');
     a.setAttribute('class', 'record-viewer');
     a.setAttribute('href', '#recordContent');
     a.innerHTML = dateString; // <--
     a.setAttribute('onclick', 'tableCreater()');
     li.appendChild(a);
   }
   ```